# how to show count for month order by month

Tags: sql-server-2008

can you help me with a sql statements to find Appid count order by month wise and year wise but don't count existing Month & year appid

```
column name     TYPE   
ID          int 
AppID           int 
Month           int 
Year            int 

Records
ID Appid Month Year
207 396 Jan 2013
250 396 Feb 2013
283 396 Mar 2013
319 396 Apr 2013
365 396 May 2013
221 451 Feb 2013
262 451 Mar 2013
293 451 Apr 2013
329 451 May 2013
384 451 June 2013
354 609 May 2013
394 702 June 2013
353 707 May 2013
```

I want the output as below,

```
Month      count
January     1
February    1
March       0
April       0
May         2
June        1
```

For example, if the appid =396 i want to show only the minimum month records count for all appid that's only Feb value is 1

Comment: What logic are you using to magically ignore the actual counts?

Comment: Why is `Feb = 1`, not 2?  I think you need to clarify the logic on how you get the output.

Comment: For example, if the appid =396 i want to show only the minimum month records count for all appid that's only Feb value is 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you want to count each `Appid` only on its first month. So, assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Appid ORDER BY ID)
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT  A.[Year],
        A.[Month],
        COUNT(B.ID)
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT [Year], [Month]
        FROM YourTable) A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE RN = 1) B
    ON A.[Year] = B.[Year] 
    AND A.[Month] = B.[Month]
GROUP BY A.[Year],
         A.[Month]
```

Comment: +1, except that the months are out of order. Absolutely unacceptable .

Answer (score 2):

Given your sample records, the output (on planet Earth) would look like:

```
| MONTH |   COUNT  |
--------------------
|   Apr |        2 |
|   Feb |        2 |
|   Jan |        1 |
|  June |        2 |
|   Mar |        2 |
|   May |        4 |
```

Which comes from

```
SELECT Month, COUNT(*)
FROM gargle
GROUP BY Month
```

Which begs the questions...

1. What logic are you using to change the record counts in your desired result?
2. Are you trying to fill in the missing months for a *specific* `appid`?
3. Why are you storing `month` and `year` separately and not as a `date` column?

Comment: sample records are available on top named as Records   
For example, if the appid =396 i want to show only the minimum month records count for all appid that's only Feb value is 1

Comment: Maybe you should have made that clear in your ***question***?